# What exactly does "exact" and "broad" mean in keywords adwords tool?

Tags: keywords, google-ads

I have read several articles on this, but still fail to understand.

For example I have the following keywords in adwords:

```
Cheese in NY - Volume: 22.000 searches
Cheese NY - Volume 22.000 searches
```

and

```
[Cheese in NY] - Volume: 100 searches
[Cheese NY] - Volume: 90 searches
```

Why the big difference?

As far as I understand [keyword] does not mean its actually typed in in quotes.

So if only 100 people use Cheese in NY, where do the other 21k searches come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exact Keywords**

This should be pretty obvious but this is when people type exactly the same keywords as your targetted ad, for example if you pay for an ad that is `Buy A Pet Rabbit Today` and then someone types exact into Google then this becomes an exact search. Your add will only be revealed when they type the exact search.

**Phrase Match**

If you bid on `Pet Rabbit` as "phrase match" then your ad will show for anything that contains the phrase such as:

- I want a pet rabbit
- Why is my pet rabbit naughty
- Why is my pet rabbit circling me
- What can pet rabbits eat

This can cause lots of useless clicks if the person is not looking to purchase and in turn would not be seen as a return of investment. Generally with good keyword research exact is the better of the two.

**Broad Match**

Broad match also has synonyms and phrases with synonyms such as "Pet Bunny", "Rabbits as Pets", and "How do I keep a bunny as a pet?"

Comment: What you say is broad is actually "Phrase Match".  Broad match also has synonyms and phrases with synonyms such as "Pet Bunny", "Rabbits as Pets", and "How do I keep a bunny as a pet?"

Comment: got the two mixed up :P

Comment: I don't use adwords at all really, I use keyword tools which have slightly different meanings to each but thanks.. Hope you don't mind I've added your comment to my answer :P

Comment: ok so broad means its actually a group of related keywords. Now i only use adwords for keyword research. How could I find out what this group is made out of?

Comment: according to your answer it seems phrase match and broad match are the same basically including multiple keywords :/

Comment: No, broad includes synonyms... such as rabbit, bunny.... Buy, Purchase,... feline, cat, kitten.... dog, puppy etc..